# Troubleshooting Symbol Loading Issues - Visual Studio 2019 - Step Into no longer working

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2019, full-trust

Quite suddenly no symbols are loading correctly for my UWP project in Visual Studio. When I establish a breakpoint, then press Step Into, every time it says that the appropriate symbol is not loaded.

Previously, this was working fine and did not throw these symbol load errors so it seems I must have messed something up but have no clue as to what.

I recently modified my UWP application to include a full trust helper.

I know this is quite vague but wondering where I should start when troubleshooting this kind of issue?

So far I have:

- Restarted my machine
- Rebuilt my project
- Deleted OBJ and BIN folder in explorer
- Deleted visual studio temporary memory

Any ideas as to what I should look into?

Comment: The fact that you can set a breakpoint indicates that the basic plumbing is working.  But not for a dependent assembly perhaps, odd that you did not mention that.  Debug > Windows > Modules to diagnose, you're interested in "User code" and "Symbol status".  Right-click > Symbol Load Information to see where it looked for the pdb.

Comment: Interesting thread.  I'm debugging a suspected CrowdStrike end point protection issue with VS2019 no longer loading symbols.  This information looks to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build configuration of the solution or some of your projects within may have changed at some point, it's normally what catches me out.

**Build Configuration:**

Open `Build \ Configuration Manager` and check the project you're expecting symbols from is set to a debug based configuration. Symbols are not included in release builds by default.

[image: Configuration Manager]

**Project Configuration:**

Open `Project \ {ProjectName} Properties \ Build \ Output \ Advanced...` and ensure that debugging information is **not** set to 'None' ('Pdb-only' or 'Portable' is fine)

[image: Advanced Build Settings]

*Note: I don't have the reputation to post this as a comment yet, sorry!*

Comment: This was it! I went to: Open Project \ {ProjectName} Properties \ Build \ Output \ Advanced... and debugging information was set to full. Changed this to Portable and VS2019 was able to find symbols again. I also had a problem with source .cs files not being found and resolved that by following the process described here to reset import/export settings: https://www.technipages.com/visual-studio-reset-all-settings

Answer (score 1):

You could check the following steps to do this.

1. Right click project->**Properties**->**Build** -> **Advanced**->Set **Debugging information** to Full
2. Select **Tools**-> **Import and Exprot settings**-> **Reset all settings**
3. When debugging, open **Debug**->**Windows**->**Modules**. You could right click .dll ->**Symbol Load information**, check if the pdf file exists. If it contains "cannot find or open the pdb file" error message, you could right click on the .dll and select **Load Symbols**, browse to the directory containing the corresponding .pdb file.